# Dataflow reading from Kafka without data loss?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're currently big users of Dataflow batch jobs and wanting to start using Dataflow streaming  if it can be done reliably.

Here is a common scenario:  We have a very large Kafka topic that we need to do some basic ETL or aggregation on and a *non idempotent* upstream queue.  Here is an example of our Kafka data:

```
    ID |     msg | timestamp (mm,ss)
-----------------------
  1    |     A   |  01:00
  2    |     B   |  01:01
  3    |     D   |  06:00
  4    |     E   |  06:01
  4.3  |     F   |  06:01
 ....  | ......  | ...... (millions more)   
  4.5  |    ZZ   |  19:58
```

Oops, the data changes from integers to decimals at some point, which will eventually cause some elements to fail, necessitating us to kill the pipeline, possibly modify the downstream service, and possibly make minor code changes to the Dataflow pipeline.

In Spark Structured Streaming, because of the ability to use external checkpoints, we would be able to restart a streaming job and resume processing the queue where the previous job left off (successfully processing) for exactly once processing.  In a vanilla or spring boot Java Application we could loop through with a Kafka consumer, *and only after writing results to our 'sink'*, commit offsets.

My overall question is **can we achieve similar functionality in Dataflow?**   I'll list some of my assumptions and concerns:

1. It seems here in [KafkaIO](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L1860) there is not a relationship between the offset commit PCollection and the User's one, does that mean they can drift apart?
2. It seems here in [KafkaOffsetCommit](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaCommitOffset.java#L124) this is taking a *window of five minutes* and emitting the highest offset, but this is **not wall time**, this is Kafka record time.  Going back to our sample data, to me it looks like the entire queue's offset would be committed (in chunks of five minutes) as fast as possible!  **This means that if we have only finished processing up to record F in the first five minutes, we may have committed almost the entire queue's offsets?**

Now in our scenario our Pipeline started failing around F, it seems our only choice is to start from the beginning or lose data? I believe this might be overcome with a lot of custom code (Custom DoFn to ensure the Kafka Consumer never commits) and some custom code for our upstream sink that would eventually commit offsets.  Is there a better way to do this, and/or are some my assumptions wrong about how offset management is handled in Dataflow?

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for the detailed question!

1. In Beam (hence Dataflow), all of the outputs for a "bundle" are committed together, along with all state updates, checkpoints, etc, so there is no drift between different output PCollections. In this specific case, the offsets are extracted directly from the elements to be output so they correspond precisely. The outputs and offsets are both durably committed to Dataflow's internal storage before the offset is committed back to Kafka.
2. You are correct that the offsets *from the elements already processed* are grouped into 5 minute event time windows (Kafka record time) and the maximum offset is taken. While 5 minutes is an arbitrary duration, the offsets correspond to elements that have been successfully pulled off the queue.

Comment: Thank you for responding.

1.  This is helpful to know, I confess that my understanding of how bundles work is very limited.  

2. I'm still unsure of how this would impact my example scenario, to me it seems possible that with the above data, given a certain window/trigger for aggregation, elements up to msg ```ZZ``` could be pulled off the queue, and then committed by the KafkaOffsetCommit timeline, when only element ```E``` is outputted, and subsequent msgs fail to output to my sink?   Then I need to reprocess the entire queue, since according to Kafka Offsets, ```ZZ``` was processed?

Comment: The elements and their offsets will all be read off the queue and committed atomically to Dataflow's internal storage. Then the offsets will be read from Dataflow's internal storage and committed to Kafka.

Comment: @Vincent Regarding your "2" state. Do you mean that there is a possible scenario when "ZZ" message has been read and its offset was already committed but it's still not processed downstream, and your pipeline is failing in this time because of error in processing of "E" message that has been read before?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanenko yes, that's exactly what i'm asking, is there a way to ensure that my pipeline only commits the offsets for elements that have been emitted downstream?  

Otherwise it seems to me that there could be data loss.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I don't think that Beam provides such functionality, like "exactly once processing", out of the box. In this case, you would probably need to commit offsets  by yourself once your records (or bundle of records) were processed.